# problem with returning some lists in Json : ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I am creating an API which returns some results from a MySql database. I have a table including 2 rows and some fields. The main factor for query is a field called `Title`. The application should return results based on the "title" field. The `titles` of these two records are **Sweet Street** and **Sweet Street 2**.

for returning the results as JSON, I have created a class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace IMES_Backend.Controllers
{
    internal class Movie
    {
        public class BaseResponse
        {
            public List<Item> search { get; set; } = new List<Item>();
            public bool response { get; set; }

        }

        public class Item
        {
            public string title { get; set; }
            public string year { get; set; }
            public string released { get; set; }
            public string runTime { get; set; }
            public string genre { get; set; }
            public string director { get; set; }
            public string writer { get; set; }
            public string actors { get; set; }
            public string language { get; set; }
            public string country { get; set; }
            public string awards { get; set; }
            public string poster { get; set; }
            public string imdbScore { get; set; }
            public string production { get; set; }
            public string dl480p { get; set; }
            public string dl720p { get; set; }
            public string dl1080p { get; set; }
            public string subtitleLink { get; set; }
            public string dubLink { get; set; }
            public string description { get; set; }
            public string state { get; set; }

        }
    }
}
```

Then I select that 2 rows as previously mentioned and return the results in JSON:

```
    [Route("IMES/api/GET/search/t={movieTitle}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult MovieSearch(string movieTitle)
    {
        string searchKeyword = movieTitle.Replace("%20", " ");

        //Try to connect to the database
        try
        {
            DB.dbConnection.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from Movies where Title LIKE '%" + searchKeyword + "%'",DB.dbConnection);
            DB.dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (DB.dataReader.Read())
            {
                baseResponse.response = true;

                //Create a list for storing the movie's data
                baseResponse.search.Add(new Movie.Item
                {
                    title = DB.dataReader.GetString(1),
                    year = DB.dataReader.GetString(2),
                    released = DB.dataReader.GetString(3),
                    runTime = DB.dataReader.GetString(4),
                    genre = DB.dataReader.GetString(5),
                    director = DB.dataReader.GetString(6),
                    writer = DB.dataReader.GetString(7),
                    actors = DB.dataReader.GetString(8),
                    language = DB.dataReader.GetString(9),
                    country = DB.dataReader.GetString(10),
                    awards = DB.dataReader.GetString(11),
                    poster = DB.dataReader.GetString(12),
                    imdbScore = DB.dataReader.GetString(13),
                    production = DB.dataReader.GetString(14),
                    dl480p = DB.dataReader.GetString(15),
                    dl720p = DB.dataReader.GetString(16),
                    dl1080p = DB.dataReader.GetString(17),
                    subtitleLink = DB.dataReader.GetString(18),
                    dubLink = DB.dataReader.GetString(19),
                    description = DB.dataReader.GetString(20),
                    state = DB.dataReader.GetString(21),
                });

                string response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(baseResponse);
                return Ok(response);

            }
        }
        catch(MySqlException ex) //MySql connection problem
        {
            return Ok(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            DB.dbConnection.Close();
            DB.dataReader.Close();
        }
        baseResponse.response = false;
        string error = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(baseResponse.response);
        return Ok(error);
    }
```

When I browse the `.../IMES/api/GET/search/t=sweet`, I just get the first rows data, there is no second list for the second row which includes the keyword `sweet`.

I want to get the both rows' data in separated lists in JSON.
Can anyone help?

> Note: I have tried the query in SQL Studio and I have received two records. So I'm sure about that 2 rows!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning from the while loop

```
while(){
    retun Ok(response);
}
```

, so it is returned after the first item is added.
Move it outside of the while loop

```
while(){
 //do stuff
}
string response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(baseResponse);
return Ok(response);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! that works. Can you please specify how can I name the lists? for example I want to name the list one as 'Item1' and the second as 'Item2'

Comment: I'd create a dictionary Dictionary<string, Item>, where string is either guid or something else ('Item1', 'Item2')
P.S.
If the answer works, could you please select it as answer (press the tick)?:)

Comment: also, I'd advise using parameterised SQL - anyone could drop your database with your current setup!